# Enum parameter sent from C# WS client is received as null by Java WS

Tags: c#, java, web-services, jboss, enums

I have the following scenario: I implemented a Java WS running on JBoss 5.1 (with Seam 2.2.0.GA):

```
@Name("service")
@WebService(name = "Service", serviceName = "Service", targetNamespace = "http://app.service")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@Stateless
public class Service implements ServiceContract { 

    @Override
    @WebMethod(operationName = "serviceOperation")
    public OperationResponse serviceOperation(@WebParam(name = "queryType") QueryType queryType) {

        this.log.info(queryType);

        // Validate queryType is not null:
        if (queryType == null) {
            return new OperationResponse("queryType is null");
        }

        // ... elided

        return new OperationResponse("Query OK");
    }

}

@XmlType
public enum QueryType {
    LOCAL,
    REMOTE;
}

@XmlType(name = "operationResponse", propOrder = {"message"})
public class OperationResponse {

    private String message;

    public OperationResponse () {

    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

A Java client consumes it just fine:

```
public class ServiceClient {

    public void consume() {
        OperationResponse response = svc.serviceOperation(QueryType.LOCAL);
        this.log.info("rcop = #0", response.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The service prints:

```
INFO [Service] LOCAL
```

The client prints:

```
INFO [ServiceClient] Query OK
```

Nevertheless, if consumed from a C# client (generated with VS 2008), the Java WS gets queryType as null

```
INFO [Service]
```

even when the parameter is set:

```
Service svc = new Service();
serviceOperation svcParams = new serviceOperation();
svcParams.queryType = queryType.LOCAL;
operationResponse response = svc.serviceOperation(svcParams);
Console.WriteLine(response.@return.message);
```

The client prints:

```
queryType is null
```

What is the reason for the service getting a null instead of the value set by the C# client? I have already searched the web and found nothing related to this problem. Am I missing any annotations for the enum in the Java side? Or is it a problem with the client generated by VS? Thanks four your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution that I don't really like, but it works. Instead of using the enum parameter, I changed the method's signature to

```
public OperationResponse serviceOperation(@WebParam(name = "queryType") String queryType)
```

where queryType must be one of "LOCAL" or "REMOTE", then I get the enum instance by using [Enum#valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29). I really needed the enum because later I added a abstract method to the enum class and each instance must implement a specific behavior.